# Windows %CD% environment variable not being updated

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this simple batch file (test.bat):

```
echo %CD%
pause
```

No matter where I run this .bat file from (i.e. C:\some\dir\test.bat), my system tells me that I'm in C:\ . This is obviously neither the intended nor the desired behavior, and if I try the exact same script on a *different machine*, it behaves as expected, giving me current directory of the .bat file. I've been googling for hours now and haven't been able to find anything relevant to my issue. Perhaps I missed up a windows setting somewhere? I have no idea, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is this happening in a brackets block? Are you changing the directory with a one on the same drive?

Comment: The current directory of the cmd.exe process is not the same thing as the script directory. The script is `%0`. Single-percent variables support a special "~" syntax to get additional information, such as the [d]rive and [p]ath components. Thus the path of the script directory is `%~dp0`. This includes a trailing backslash.

Comment: Further to Eryksuns comment, if you throw in `%~dpnx0` then it will show you the full path `C:\some\dir\test.bat`.
Have a check out of [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3679781/5552766)

Comment: I guess you set CD to `C:\ ` somewhere. Try to unset CD using `set "CD="`. Or try the other shadow variable `echo %__CD__%`. The `__CD__` variable can't be hidden by a self assigned variable, see also [Why can't I access a variable named CD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156490/why-cant-i-access-a-variable-named-cd-on-windows-7/20169219#20169219)

Comment: @npocmaka - no, it's not in a brackets block, the code above are the only two lines in the script.

Comment: @eryksun - I am aware of that, but I would like to extract the current directory from where the shell is launched. Futhermore, based on documented behavior, the %CD% var should also provide the same information because it's tied to the shell right?

Comment: @jeb - The script doesn't contain anything else besides the two lines above; are you implying that %CD% is a global var that can be changed by different shells? I thought it was unique to a single shell. Anyways, I'll try your ideas tomorrow!

Comment: Normally `%CD%` is a dynamic variable, but when it is manually set, you only see the value of the environment variable, the dynamic value will be invisible/hidden then. You could also test it on the command line with `echo %CD%` and `set CD`. CD should be undefined

Comment: The question said the desired result is the "current directory of the .bat file", which is not necessarily the working directory. As to "from where the shell is launched", typically it's launched by Explorer, using a working directory that could be set by (1) a .LNK shortcut, (2) the user's profile directory if the shell was run from the Win+R dialog, or (3) the script directory if the shell was run by clicking on a .bat or .cmd file. If you run the script from the command line, it should execute in the current shell and thus have the same working directory.

Comment: @eryksun - Apologies for any confusion; the desired result IS indeed the "current directory of the .bat file", but I am running the .bat file using option (3): by clicking on the .bat file. If such is the case, shouldn't the working of the shell directory be the same as the directory of the .bat file? This is my issue! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: there was an AutoRun registry entry that would change directory to C:\ whenever a shell was opened. *facepalm*