# How to call _wsystem without showing console?

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file

I would like to copy a file to a destination by using batch command in my code.

```
    szCommand.Format(_T("copy \"%s\" \"%s\""), szOrg, szTargetFile);
    _wsystem(szCommand);
```

However, each time _wsystem is called, a console window will be prompted, which is very unpleasant.

Is there a way to call _wsystem without showing out the console window? Or any other alternative?

Comment: Ditch the console app and do this from a GUI app. Also see: http://flipcode.com/archives/Win32_ConsoleWindowed_Tip.shtml

Comment: Thanks to all answers. I finally chose CopyFile WIN32 function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To exert control over how a new program appears, use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx). Then you can use the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` [process-creation flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863.aspx) to hide the window of a console program.

But to copy a file from one place to another, skip the external programs and just call [`CopyFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851.aspx).

Comment: Or [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164.aspx) with `FO_COPY`, if a nice graphical progress display is desired.

Answer (score 1):

Why shell-out when there's a Win32 API that will copy a file for you.  It's called CopyFile!

Details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851%28VS.85%29.aspx

```
#include <windows.h>

CopyFileA(szOrg, szTargetFile, FALSE);  // use CopyFileW if szOrg and szTargetFile are unicode strings
```

Answer (score 0):

Would having the window minimized be okay?  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106723/how-to-minimize-the-command-prompt-when-running-a-batch-script).