# how to miminize a program to tray with a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How would you minimize a running windows service using batch file or cmd  lets say firefox.exe to  start up and run minimized or minimized to system tray?

Comment: Do any of these asnwers point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106723/how-to-minimize-the-command-prompt-when-running-a-batch-script

Comment: not very helpful ... talks on minimizing the cmd

Comment: @jimmyobonyo Its the same thing if you call **start /min firefox** it will start minimized. However theres a caveat dont do this with Firefox window open because then it will not do this, unless you start a new session. There is no way for batch to start things in the system tray unless the software itself has switches for this. But then that's not a batch issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call start /min firefox it will start minimized. However theres a caveat dont do this with Firefox window open because then it will not do this, unless you start a new session. There is no way for batch to start things in the system tray unless the software itself has switches for this. But then that's not a batch issue

Comment: Did you just copy paste a comment as answer?