# How do I run a batch file with WinExec?

Tags: batch-file, windows-3.1

I'm using Windows 3.11, and in answer to [a question about running batch files with certain attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2106723/33732), someone suggested using `WinExec`. How do I do that? Is there something special to do because it's a batch file instead of a normal program?

Answer (score 2):

Starting a batch file with [`WinExec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687393.aspx) is the same as starting anything else with `WinExec`. The first parameter is the command line to run, and the second parameter is the window-display parameter, indicating how you'd like the new program's window to appear. For example, in C:

```c
WinExec("foo.bat", SW_SHOW);
```

Note that `WinExec` has been obsolete since Windows 95. Preferred functions to use instead include [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) and [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx).